# iPhone - Zoom view

Tags: iphone, ios, zooming

I have an UIView. Over that Iam adding an UIImageView as subview. I want to zoom in the main view when Iam touching the UIImageview. When touch is not there, then it should zoom out. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you do is give mainView's tag 100, then write below code

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
         [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
  }



  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     UITouch    *touch = [touches anyObject];
      if (!([touch view].tag == 100)) {




if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    lastScale = 1.0;//lastscale is CGFLoat defiend in .h file
}

CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = babyImage.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[babyImage setTransform:newTransform];
lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];


     }
 }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can i have some points please??? you can zoom in and zoom out with the same function my friend....!!!!

Comment: you can zoom in and zoom out with the same function , i think you are not getting view's tag 100 because you are not touching mainview..

Comment: what is sender i tried above code but giving error to sender as undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code for the viewcontroller.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIImage *image;
    UIImageView *img;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch;
}

@end
```

Following Code for the viewcontroller.m file

In  viewDidLoad method use for the initialize image view and UIPinchGestureRecognizer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    zoomInButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    zoomOutButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    img.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    img.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeCenter;
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:img];

    twoFingerPinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                      initWithTarget:self
                      action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)];
    [img addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPinch];
}
```

And Accessing the zoom in/out method for scaling the image view this also use into UIViewController Also.

```
- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //    NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
    if (recognizer.scale >1.0f && recognizer.scale < 2.5f) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
        img.transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To zoom into images, you can use the UIScrollView as a parent view to your UIImageView.

- Set the minimum and maximum scaling properties of the scroll view as per your requirement. I set the min scale as 1 and max scale as 2/3 based of the max image size.
- You will also be required to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate and when you implement

  ```
  - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  ```

  return your UIImageView outlet object.
- Additionality you can implement a tap gesture recognizer on your scroll view to zoom into original size when double tapped.

This will take care of your zooming. Enjoy.